# Conditional expectation of $XY^2$ given $X=5$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I have a joint density of $\pi(x,y) = 2e^{-x-y}$, where $0\leq x \leq y$

and conditional distribution is $\pi(y|x) = e^{x-y}$, where $0\leq x \leq y$

and want to solve for $E(XY^2|X=5)$

Let $X = h(X)$, then $E(XY^2|X=5) = E(h(X)Y^2|X=5)= \int_{5}^{\infty} h(X)y^2\cdot\pi_{Y|X}(Y|X=5)\, dy$ $=h(X)\int_{5}^{\infty}y^2\cdot e^{5-y}\,dy = 37\cdot h(X) = 37X$

Really puzzled about 2 points here. What was done above essentially means that $E(h(X)Y^2|X=5) = h(X)E(Y^2|X=5)$ but I haven't come across this so far... And $E(XY^2|X=5)=37X$, which still has a random variable X in it, which is weird because we already have that $X=5$, so there shouldn't be any X terms floating around.

Apologies if this was a stupid question. I pondered over it for a while now, and need the insight of others.

Comment: Why do you do $X=h(X)$? What does that mean when $h$ is not the identity?

Comment: Note $$E(XY^2|X=5)=5E(Y^2|X=5)$$

Comment: You forgot to substitute X=5. You can always factor out conditional constants.

Comment: It's not $h(X)$. It's $h(X|X=5) = h(5) = 5$.

Comment: Thank you everyone! Now I clearly see where I went wrong